# How to modify Vtiger with php?

Tags: javascript, php, vtiger

How can I change let say tickets in vtiger I think how to modify inputs with javascript or php. Or can someone tell me how to put my code in vtiger?

Comment: As your are new here please go through with http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Please try to explain your query in detail? What you want to achieve? What you have tried?

Comment: i ned to creat a php file and edit to vtiger

Answer (score 0):

If you are new in vTiger then go thorugh with below links and try to clear basic concepts of using / customizing vTiger.

1. [Developer guide](http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/develop-extensions-for-vtiger.html)
2. [Get Started with vTiger](https://wiki.vtiger.com/vtiger6/index.php/Main_Page)
3. [UI types](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/UI_Types)

Hope this post will help you to understand vtiger basics.

Comment: so you saying that i can put my on php or javascript cod in vtiger?????

Comment: Yes. You can customize the vTiger modules easily using PHP, Javascript.

Comment: thank you but i dont know how to start.. if you understand me i dont know wher shud i put my php file that bothering me